# Check inputs in csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I`m new to python. I have a csv file. I need to check whether the inputs are correct or not. The ode should scan through each rows. 
All columns for a particular row should contain values of same type: Eg:
All columns of second row should contain only string, 
All columns of third row should contain only numbers... etc

I tried the following approach, (it may seem blunder):

I have only 15 rows, but no idea on number of columns(Its user choice)
df.iloc[1].str.isalpha()
This checks  for string. I don`t know how to check ??

Comment: Please show the code you have thus far.

Comment: In a standard dataset, a column contains similar type of data, and a row can contains different pieces of data regarding the same observation, for example a string 'name', an int 'id', a float 'hieght'. Are you sure you are not mixing rows and columns?

Comment: In my case its just the opposite: All test cases are represented by each column. Each rows of a column represents, start time, end time, Name, Path etc... I need to check whether any string has gone into start time or end time etc...

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach that can be modified:

1. Open df using `df = pandas.from_csv(<path_to_csv>)`
2. For each column, use `df['<column_name>'] = df['<column_name>'].astype(str)` (str = string, int = integer, float = float64, ..etc).

You can check column types using `df.dtypes`